# swap string a in place to string b in C++

Tags: c++, string, swap

swap string a in reverse to b.
swap string a in place to string b in C++

// 1e9+5

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std; 


int main ()
{
    string a="Hello,Sir";
    string b="";

    int k=5;
    int last=k; 
    for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
    b[i]=a[last--];

    cout << b;

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Beg your pardon, what?

Comment: The string `b` is empty, so all `b[i]` will be out of range. You might want to try [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) before using `b`.

Comment: The bug, and the reason for your crash are very obvious, but since there is no cogent question here, I see no reason to provide an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you typically use [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) for exchanging two objects, e.g.

```
std::string a = "Hello", b = "world";
std::swap(a, b);
```

---

For [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), there's also [`std::basic_string::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/swap)

> Exchanges the contents of the string with those of other. All iterators and references may be invalidated.

```
a.swap(b);
```